# Excel file size efficiency

Tags: database, excel

I am working with an organisation that is using Excel as their data storage center right now, their data might scale up in the near future, so I was wondering when the data size is too large for Excel to handle efficiently. The data stored is just strings and integers of limited lengths (below 50 char and integer values between 1 and 100000).

Is there some kind of general guideline to how big an Excel sheet can be before it becomes inefficient and you should use a database like SQL Server instead?

Comment: Efficient or not, this sounds like a great opportunity to switch to a database. There's a reason everyone else does it that way.

Comment: For arguments, see e.g. http://schoolofdata.org/2013/11/07/sql-databases-vs-excel/

Answer (score 0):

I have usually found that once the Excel file size crosses 30MB it becomes very slow and unresponsive. In order to manipulate higher data size i started using a add-on called Powerpivot which is very very fast ! See instructions on how to enable it here - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Start-the-Power-Pivot-in-Microsoft-Excel-add-in-a891a66d-36e3-43fc-81e8-fc4798f39ea8

Answer (score 0):

Efficiency is subjective and depends on your goals. The thing is that an RDBMS like SQL Server will always be more efficient, because you will get optimized searches instead of reading a textual file. Also, relations between tables are handled well and if you design your DB scheme well, then you will have benefits like handling concurrent access, avoiding redundancy and inconsistency. It is worth the effort on the long run.